# mysql SUM() in a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I have points table with data as follows:

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | user_id | points |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |     1   |   10   |
|  2 |     3   |    5   |
|  3 |     1   |   12   |
|  4 |     2   |   27   |
|  5 |     1   |   14   |
+----+---------+--------+
```

i need user-id's from above data those points sum is greater than 10

like

```
+--------+
| userid |
+--------+
|   1    |
|   2    |
+--------+
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't user `WHERE` in your query since you are trying to operate on aggregates of users.  Instead, use a `GROUP BY` along with a `HAVING` clause like this:

```
SELECT t.user_id FROM
table t
GROUP BY t.user_id
HAVING SUM(t.points) > 10
```

Here is a **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16e48/1)** where you can test this query.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
select user_id from tablename
group by user_id
having sum(points)>10
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `group by` and `having`:

```
select user_id
from TableName
group by user_id
having sum(points)>10
```

Sample result:

```
user_id
-------
1
2
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5de97/2)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [having](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause:

```
select userid
from `table`
group by user_id
having sum(points) > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use aggregate expressions in the `where` clause. You could, however, use a `having` clause. It act similarly to a `where` clause in the sense that it's used to filter out results, but it's applied **after** the `group by` clause, so it can act on aggregate expressions too:

```
SELECT   user_id
FROM     points
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING   SUM(points) > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query with having:

```
select user_id 
from [your_table] 
group by user_id 
having sum(points)>10
```